# Ubuntu samba/raid server shutdown fails

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown

I'm moving an Ubuntu 10.4.04 LTS server and the shutdown sequence froze. What are my options?

**The Story** *(or skip to what I think my options are below)*
I actually don't ever shut it down... the last time was when the power went out & it ran out the UPS. *When hooking it back up, I installed the USB cable and made the notification for graceful shutdown work.*

So this time, I did my usual SSH in and run `sudo shutdown -h 1 &` that I do for my other servers all the time, like for the firewall computer that did shutdown and all was well. The samba / raid server has a 4TB raid 5 array (which also got its own battery backup with that last power outage failure). I went to move the raid server and it is still on. It is not responding to the console. It will let me <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to switch to different TTYs. It will not respond to typing or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>. This was on the PS2 keyboard. Plugging in the USB Dell keyboard gets same results. The console has no information either.

Once the network was back up after re-racking the switch and firewall I can't SSH into the raid server. It replies to pings and traceroute. And its nginx webserver is still running, which tells me something is going wrong. The samba server isn't running, or I could set up some kind of webpage using php to issue commands.

Right now, I've left it on for the night in case it is trying to fsck or something and will come in the morning and do something:

**What I think my options are**:

1. Pull the plug on the UPS so it sends graceful shutdown to the server and see if that does something. UPS will last at least 1/2 hour. If it doesn't shutdown, try next step.
2. I'll press the power switch on the box and force the power off.
3. Something else I'm not thinking of?

Are there other things I can do rather than force the power off?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up pulling the plug on the server and it booted up normally without issue after being moved. The raid mounted and did not lose any data. I'm using a RocketRaid PCI card with its piggy-back battery pack. So perhaps this is what helped me save the data.